# Why is the objective function for GLM equal to $-\ln p(Y | \hat{Y})$?

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model

The following quote is from a set of lecture notes:

> When fitting generalised linear models, the objective function is canonically the log - probability of $Y|X$ (essentially, the log - likelihood with data $Y|X$ and weight parameters W). Equivalently, we minimise
> $L(Y, \hat{Y}) := -\ln P(Y | \hat(Y(X))$ where the conditional distribution $p$ is assumed, and is parameterised by its mean $\hat{Y} = E[Y|X]$

How should I convince myself that $L(Y, \hat{Y}) := -\ln P(Y | \hat{Y}(X))$?

Comment: The TL;DR is that *minimizing* the **negative** log-likelihood is the equivalent to *maximizing* the (log-)likelihood. The duplicates show the details.